# Convert PSS/E .raw file to Pandapower

Tags: psse, pandapower

I'm trying to find a possible way to convert PSS/E native .raw files to Pandapower format.
My objective is to take advantage of the network plotting capabilities that are available in Pandapower.
For that, I have to first be able to load my grid data into Pandapower.
For that, I have to somehow bridge the gap between PSSE .raw to Pandapower.

Literature says that a possible way of doing this is by using the 'psse2mpc' function available in Matpower.
I've tried to use it but I get the following error message:

(quote)

```
>> psse2mpc('RED1523.raw')
Reading file 'RED1523.raw' ............................................. done.
Splitting into individual lines ...error: regexp: the input string is invalid UTF-8
error: called from
    psse_read at line 60 column 9
    psse2mpc at line 68 column 21
```

(unquote)

I'was informed that maybe I should save my .raw file (natively generated with a PSSE/E v33 version) into an older .raw format (corresponding to previous PSS/E versions).

I've tried this as well but still have the same error message.

Apart from getting this error which so far impedes to reach my objective, I've been unable to guess the Pandapower "equivalent .raw" structure. Does anybody know how this input structure looks like in Pandapower?

If I would know how Pandapower needs to get the input data, I could even try to code a taylor-made python script that converts my .raw file into whatever is required from Pandapower.

If somebody could help me to get out of this labyrinth I would be most gratefull !!!

Thanks.

Eneko.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your .raw file to enter the other Inputs of the psse2mpc function. For instance, if I have the case39.raw file and I want to convert it to matpower format like case39mpc.m, then I must enter something like this:

psse2mpc ('case39.raw', 'case39mpc.m', '1', '29')

Answer (score 0):

Check [Andes](https://github.com/CURENT/andes) lib on GitHub and check below link
you can convert the .raw file into a dataframe of Panda power
https://docs.andes.app/en/latest/examples/pandapower.html

```
ssa = andes.load(andes.get_case(IEEE39.raw),
                         setup=False,
                         no_output=True,
                         default_config=True)
      
ssa.setup()


ssp = to_pandapower(ssa)
```